# Set a background to the area out of camera limits (Viewport Rect) in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, background, camera

I am talking about the Camera settings in Unity3D.

I'm trying to figure out if I can change (at least) the background color of the gray area in the screenshot. The limits of the camera are changed programmatically. The motivation lies in the fact that the playing area has to change dynamically based on whether a child or an adult is playing. The screen is huge around more than 83 inches. When rescaling the playing area, the area that is not drawn is gray and a bit ugly, I would like to know if you can define at least the color, or better still if possible with an image.

The screenshot you see is the screen capture in fullscreen mode, so it includes all the pixels.

[image]

After this brief explanation in words and images, let's go to the specifics of the technical details. This is how I resize the room design area:

```
public static void SetViewportCalibration()
{
    var camera = Camera.main;
    camera.pixelRect = new Rect(MinX, MinY, MaxX, MaxY);
}
```

Is it possible to set the color of that gray area outside the new `Rect(MinX, MinY, MaxX, MaxY)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways off the top of my head to accomplish this. Both ways use two Cameras.

*The first way*. Create a second Camera. The second Camera should have `Depth` LESS than the dynamic camera. This second, "Background" camera can then display anything you'd like, for example, a separate Skybox, a separate UI, other scene content, etc. etc.

*The second way*. Your dynamic camera is actually not resized dynamically. Instead, render your camera to a `Target Texture`. Use this texture in a material, and assign the material to a Quad mesh (most appropriate). This mesh can then be used in your scene like any other 3D object, which means not only can you position it, but scale it and even rotate it. The new camera that you added can have it's own Skybox, UI etc. etc.

I would opt for the second way. Partly personal preference, but also because it sounds like it might suit your situation better and be easier to implement. You can also implement many more effects for extra "wow".

Comment: using a second camera with a rendertexture has a serious downside - there's no easy way to use the UI system without doing some semi - serious hacking

Answer (score 4):

Try to create another camera with no objects in its view and the following settings:

**Clear Flags:** Solid Color,

**Background:** Pick a color,

**ViewPort Rect:** X = 0, y = 0, w = 1, h = 1,

**Depth:** A smaller value than the other camera (Set the depth of this camera to 0 and the depth of the other camera to 1)

This camera will work as background of your screen.

I hope that I understood the question :)